# Why to use Higher order component

Tags: reactjs, debugging, react-native, google-chrome-devtools

I am displaying contact list array.

If contacts array is empty it will show the loader else will display contact list.

I render loader using higher order component [Using this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LTunyI2Oyzw). For this I got performance summary as shown in the below image-

[image]

when i render loader using simple if else condition then i had performance graph as below -
[image]

comparing this i got to know that while using higher order component it requires more time than simple loop.

Can anyone please explain me which is better to use ? and when we should use the Higher order component ? what are advantages and disadvantages of using Higher order component ?

Comment: HOC is a function that accepts your component as an argument and returns a new function that adds some feature to the component.Details here https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Answer (score 2):

A higher order component allows you to apply functionality or data that is common amongst a number of components to a component and will return a `new` component with the functionality or data of the HoC included.

As for advantages or disadvantages. Would entirely depend on the circumstance and problem you are trying to address. You would also need to perform a long list of tests as the times are too close to really say one is quicker than the other. Also this looks like it is on your local so on production server could be an entirely different story.

But in your circumstance are you apply any extra functionality to your `<Loader />` component? If you aren't or that functionality is not going to be used anywhere else then it might be unnecessary to use a HoC in your case.

[ReactJS - Higher Order Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)

Answer (score 2):

pros for HOC:

extremly reusable around your app/projects:

```
// withShowSupport.js
export default Component => props =>
  !props.show
  ? null
  : <Component { ...props } />
```

easy testing

res:

https://www.robinwieruch.de/gentle-introduction-higher-order-components/

Answer (score 1):

New technology can lead us to be more efficient and effective in productivity. But, of course, it will also increase resource usage.

I don't have enough knowledge to explain more, but I can give you simple study case.

I have a react app which consists of several pages (how about > 10 pages?). I want to do something when each page has been rendered (In other words, page changes). If-else condition rendering? No way!

Actually, you can make an HOC named `withBase` that will wrap each page (Use it when you export your page component e.g. `export default withBase(Home)`). `withBase` will execute a function that indicates page has been changed.

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/k2opxlwm85)

Comment: but i can create a separate component to render loader and will pass visibility prop to it. it will avoid my code repetition also

Comment: How do you set its visibility?

Comment: till api response will come i will set loader visibility true as i get the response i will set it to true

Comment: You can set the loader visibility to true when **page changes**. After it gets the response, set it to false. How we can know page changes? that's job for HOC :)

Answer (score 1):

As per definition :

> HOC is a function that accepts your component as an argument and
>   returns a new function that adds some feature to the component.

A simple use case is - when you call an API to fetch some data and use them to render some content in your application, we need to show some kind of progress bar, loading indicator, etc to tell users that data is being fetched. We can use HOC for that purpose.A sample code goes here

```
import React from 'react';
import List from './List.js';
import WithLoading from './WithLoading.js';
const ListWithLoading = WithLoading(List);
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loading: false,
    repos: null
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/farskid/repos`)
      .then(json => json.json())
      .then(repos => {
        this.setState({ loading: false, repos: repos });
      });
  }
render() {
    return (
      <ListWithLoading isLoading={this.state.loading} repos={this.state.repos} />
    )
  }
}
```

the above is App.js file and below is the HOC component `WithLoading`

```
import React from 'react';
function WithLoading(Component) {
  return function WihLoadingComponent({ isLoading, ...props }) {
    if (!isLoading) return (<Component {...props} />);
    return (<p>Be Hold, fetching data may take some time :)</p>);
  }
}
export default WithLoading;
```

so in App.js, we are calling HOC like `const ListWithLoading = WithLoading(List);` and `<ListWithLoading isLoading={this.state.loading} repos={this.state.repos} />`, Where `List` is the component which is passing into the HOC. based on the `sLoading` prop, loding symbol is shown. Another one interesting thing is HOC dont have a render menthod! beacuse its a simple function !

Comment: what if i make WithLoading normal component instead of HOC. it will still work. so what is advantage to make it HOC. from your answer i understand that it don't have render method.there  are any other advantages or not?

Comment: @SamikshaJagtap another one is, HOC is a pure function with zero side-effects. So it will always return the same result if the same arguments are passed in.

Comment: thanks @Aravind S. can you please also tell me why the performance graph for HOC is less than normal component. The images for this are attached with question

Comment: What my take on this is HOC is a simple function, not a component. That may be the reason.

Answer (score 1):

By my understanding, Higher-Order-Component adds an additional layer between components or libraries for better code-reuse.

For example, you have a library file "User.class.js" that is responsible to retrive/store user data, and it's used by different components. When "User.class.js" is modified, method names changed, or parameters changed. What you gonna do? Apply changes to all those components? What if it's used by 100 different components, or even more? With Higher-Order-Component, you just need to apply the changes to one single file.